# How to split JSON string

Tags: php, regex

i have tried many ways to split the string though am not that good in this programing language
my string looks like this

```
{"success":true," URL ":"WWW.face-book.com", "rank":9, "details":null}
```

how do i separate my strings in such a way that the output looks like-

```
URL: WWW.face-book.com
rank: 9
```

Comment: Start by looking at [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

You use `json_decode($yourJsonStringHere);` and youll get an Object of the class "stdClass" with public properties for all your keys.

So you can basically do the following:

```
$jsonObj=json_decode($jsonString);
echo $jsonObj->URL;
echo $jsonObj->rank;
echo $jsonObj->success;
echo $jsonObj->details;
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php for more info on the function itself.